# How do I convert 'May 17, 2017' to date in sql?

Tags: sql, amazon-redshift

I keep getting the error when using `to_date('May 17, 2017','Mon DD, YYYY')`

> Amazon Invalid operation: invalid value for MON/Mon/mon;

Answer (score 0):

> If the COPY command does not recognize the format of your date or time values, or if your date and time values use formats different from each other, use the `'auto'` argument with the TIMEFORMAT parameter. The `'auto'` argument recognizes several formats that are not supported when using a DATEFORMAT and TIMEFORMAT string.

From: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_DATEFORMAT_and_TIMEFORMAT_strings.html

Comment: I already tried that... but it gives error as Invalid operation: Error converting text to date

Answer (score 0):

Your `to_date()` function worked perfectly fine for me in an Amazon Redshift cluster:

```
select to_date('May 17, 2017','Mon DD, YYYY')
```

returned:

```
2017-05-17
```